# Why does the data in my buffer contain garbage values?

Tags: c, buffer

```
char buffer[51];
FILE *file;

file = fopen("...", "r");

while (fread(buffer, sizeof(char), sizeof(buffer) - 1, file) > 0) {
    buffer[strlen(buffer)] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    strcpy(buffer, "");
}
```

Let's say my file contained 75 characters. It would properly put the first 50 characters into buffer. But when it went around to putting the last 25, buffer would contain those 25, but also the second half of the first buffer. This might sound confusing, so I will show an example below.

My file looks like this

`aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccccccccccccccccc`

There are 25 a's, 25 b's, and 25 c's.

If I print each buffer, the output will be like this

`aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb`
`cccccccccccccccccccccccccbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb`

I assume it's just garbage values, which is why I tried to `strcpy()` the buffer to nothing in each iteration. Why is this happening?

Thank you.

Comment: In `buffer[strlen(buffer)] = '\0';` there is no use using `strlen` to find where to place the `'\0'` since, `strlen` needs that to function anyway. `fread` is used for binary data, `fgets` is used for text data. If you want to know how many bytes are in the buffer, you the value returned by `fread`

Comment: Replace the `strcpy(buffer, "");` with `memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));`.

Comment: @WeatherVane What happens if the file I'm reading can be any type? Is fread still okay? Thank you.

Comment: @EOF That works thank you.

Comment: @EOF fread() returns the position where a null terminator may be inserted.  memset/bzero is cargo-cult cycle-wasting.

Comment: @MartinJames: You really think `memset()` of a small buffer is relevant next to an `fread()`? Cute.

Comment: @ludluck the fact that you are trying to terminate the data with `'\0'` shows the data is *not* "any type". It is text, in which case `fread` is likely to split text lines at inconvenient places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fread()` does not append a null terminator to the read buffer, but you use of `strlen()` is expecting that.  As you noted, the second `fread()` reads fewer characters than the first `fread()` did, and it does not overwrite the remaining data that is already in the buffer.

`fread()` returns the number of items actually read, you need to use that value, eg:

```
char buffer[51];
FILE *file;
int numRead;

file = fopen("...", "r");

do {
    numRead = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), sizeof(buffer) - 1, file);
    if (numRead < 1) break;
    buffer[numRead] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
}
while (1);
```

Or:

```
char buffer[51];
FILE *file;
int numRead;

file = fopen("...", "r");

do {
    numRead = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), sizeof(buffer) - 1, file);
    if (numRead < 1) break;
    printf("%.*s\n", numRead, buffer);
}
while (1);
```